# What happens when Veritaserum and a Fidelius Charm meet?

Tags: harry-potter, fidelius-charm

The title kind of explains the question.

If a Secret Keeper was given Veritaserum, what would happen? What if the Veritaserum was willingly taken?

EDIT:

Given the answers here, I'm not sure which to pick as they both use canon sources. I will give this question another 24 hours for votes to pour in before accepting.

Comment: Interesting that the two answers thus far are on completely opposite sides of the spectrum, both using canon.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The first thing I'd say is that Veritaserum is only one tool. It may be magic, but it is not invincible, it is not infallible. Rowling has gone on record saying:

> [Veritaserum works best on] the unsuspecting, the vulnerable and those insufficiently skilled (in one way or another) to protect themselves against it.
>
> Source: [accio-quote](http://www.accio-quote.org/themes/therules.htm)

As such, in no sense can Veritaserum be relied upon to always force the truth out of someone. That, I think, is worth bearing in mind.

Secondly, the magic of the Fidelius Charm to me is rather beautiful. It's about fidelity, loyalty, trust and friendship.

> 'An immensely complex spell,' he said squeakily, 'involving the magical concealment of a secret inside a single, living soul. The information is hidden inside the chosen person, or Secret Keeper, and is henceforth impossible to find - unless, of course, the Secret Keeper chooses to divulge it. As long as the Secret Keeper refused to speak, You-Know-Who could search the village where Lily and James were staying for years and never find them, not even if he had his nose pressed against their sitting-room window!'
>
> *Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban* - pp.152-3 - Bloomsbury - Chapter 10, *The Marauder's Map*

To me, the element of choice there is all-important. The spell is broken if your Secret Keeper betrays you. It's about betrayal, infidelity, treachery.

Of course, you could choose to betray someone under duress. I would argue that if the information was tortured out of you - well that would be forgiveable, but you have still elected to give your friends up. I mean, the torture might send you out of your mind, you might lose all control and hardly know what you were saying any more, but it's still a decision you take. Overriding that autonomy with a potion that would just send your secrets pouring out of you would be different, to me. That wouldn't be betrayal. If I'm tortured into giving up your whereabouts, I have given you up - however understandably. But if somebody finds where you are by searching my house and discovering the information - well, I've been a bit careless, but I have not given you up.

So I would argue that to break the Fidelius Charm, it would have to be elective. You would have to make a decision - however constrained and inevitable that decision was. As such, Veritaserum, which would not enable you to make a choice, would be defeasible by that. It would not be able to get that information out of you.

So, Veritaserum can be fought by certain means. If you do not have those means or have failed to employ them, it will reveal your secrets without you having any control over them. As such, when it works, it cannot force a betrayal. As such, it cannot break a Fidelius Charm. As such, that is another means by which it may be fought.

Having said that, I think it's an interesting question whether extreme torture would also be vulnerable to that. I would argue that if the torture got so extreme that you lost all control, that too might not break the Fidelius Charm, because it's not a choice. However, up to a certain point in the torture (and it gives me no pleasure to speculate on where that line might be drawn), in giving up the information, you would be choosing to sacrifice your friends' lives to save you from pain. Which would be betrayal, however understandable. Which would break the Charm.

Comment: What if instead of torturing you, they tortured someone you loved?

Comment: Well, thats interesting, but drifting further from the q. I'd say there you have a choice. You choose to betray x to save y. Fair choice, but a choice. With torture, I mean, you can get people to the point where they'll say anything. Not everyone. But with most people you can completely obliterate their self-control and destroy their mind. At which point, they can hardly be said to have betrayed anyone. They've very arguably failed to protect your secret, but they've not given you up, anymore than if some evidence was found on their person and stolen from them while they were subdued

Comment: The thing is, torture is something the enemy does for fun. I'm pretty sure the Potters wouldn't have chosen this form of concealment/security if they thought torturing someone would be enough to break the spell. It is about drawing the line, but as far as I'm concerned, when someone uses violence to force you to do something, it can hardly be voluntary - it kind of sounds like a good *definition* of "voluntary" to me. I "choose" to pay my taxes, but I sure as hell don't consider them voluntary.

Comment: TIL the word "defeasible" - thank you!

Answer (score 15):

### The Secret-Keeper would reveal the location.

The fidelius charm prevents anyone who wasn't informed of the location by the Secret-keeper from finding the location.

> “An immensely complex spell,” he  said squeakily, “involving the magical  concealment  of a  secret  inside a single, living  soul. The information is hidden inside the chosen person, or  Secret-Keeper, and is henceforth impossible  to  find — unless, of  course, the Secret-Keeper chooses to divulge it. As long as the Secret-Keeper refused to speak, You-Know-Who  could search the village where Lily and James were staying for years and never find them, not even if he had his nose pressed against their sitting room window!”
>   <sub>(*Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban - Chapter 10*)</sub>

The Secret-Keeper is susceptible to force

> “So Black was the Potters’  Secret-Keeper?” whispered  Madam Rosmerta.
>   “Naturally,”  said Professor McGonagall.  “James Potter told Dumbledore that **Black would die rather than tell where they were**, that Black was planning to go into hiding himself . . . and yet, Dumbledore remained worried. I remember him offering to be the Potters’ Secret-Keeper himself.”
>   <sub>(*Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban - Chapter 10*)</sub>

> “Lily and James only made you Secret-Keeper because I suggested it,” Black hissed, so venomously that Pettigrew took  a  step backward. “I thought it  was the perfect plan . . . a bluff. . . . **Voldemort  would  be  sure  to  come  after me**, would never dream they’d use a weak, talentless thing like you. . . . It  must  have  been the finest moment  of your  miserable life, telling Voldemort you could hand him the Potters.”
>   <sub>(*Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban - Chapter 19*)</sub>

The Secret-Keeper doesn't even have to consciously be aware that he or she is revealing the location

> “But then, where’s he? Hang on. .  . . You don’t mean he’s at Grimmauld Place? He  can’t get in  there?”
>   Her eyes sparkled with  unshed tears as she nodded.
>   “Harry, **I think he  can**. I — I forced  him  to  let go with  a Revulsion Jinx, but **I’d already taken  him inside the Fidelius  Charm’s protection**. Since Dumbledore died, **we’re Secret-Keepers, so I’ve given him the secret**, haven’t  I?”
>   <sub>(*Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows - Chapter 14*)</sub>

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/79362/can-a-secret-keeper-be-forced-to-reveal-the-secret-with-the-imperius-spell

Answer (score 3):

> If a Secret Keeper was given Veritaserum, what would happen?

The secret keeper will divulge all the darkest secrets of their life, but they won't give up the secret that's under the protection of Fidelius Charm.

> If the Secret Keeper wishes to do so, they may divulge the information at any time (although **the secret cannot be forced, bewitched or tortured out of a Secret Keeper** who does not wish to give up their secret; it must be given voluntarily).
>
> <sub>From http://pottermore.wikia.com/wiki/Secret_Keeper, emphasis mine</sub>

---

> What if the Veritaserum was willingly taken?

If the secret keeper is willing to share the secret, they would not need Veritaserum. If they are not willing to share the secret, they would never willingly take the potion. The charm would still hold.

Comment: Downvoted because the wikia isn't a canon source, it often contains wild speculation presented as hard truth.